# SwiftUI: UPdate SwiftData model in real time cause Preview crashed

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I am developing a social APP, and I want to store chatting records in SwiftData.(My APP is only for display and I don't have enough time to use FireBase)

However, when I send message and update context, my PreView crash.

First, this is my `Message`

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Message: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    var createdAt: Date
    var FromUser: User
    var ToUser: User
    var isFromCurrentUser: Bool
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), text: String, createdAt: Date, FromUser: User, ToUser: User, isFromCurrentUser: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.text = text
        self.createdAt = createdAt
        self.FromUser = FromUser
        self.ToUser = ToUser
        self.isFromCurrentUser = isFromCurrentUser
    }
    
    
}
```

Then I use `chatContent` to store a user's chatting records

`var chatContent: [Message]`

At last, I will show my `ChatView`

Because user's `chatContent` store all chatting records with his all friends, so I will select this user and one of his friend to display in a single `ChatView` . So I use `displayContent`, use some logic to ensure displayContent only contains the chatting records between this user and his friend.

relative variable definition:

```
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Query private var userInfo: [User]
    @Binding var meindex: Int
    var taindex: Int
    var displayContent: [Message] {
        userInfo[meindex].chatContent.filter {
            message in
            judgemessage(message: message)
        }
    }
    @State var text = ""
```

And my send Button

```
Button {
                            if text.count >= 1 {
                                let msg = Message(text: text, createdAt: Date(), FromUser: userInfo[meindex], ToUser: userInfo[taindex], isFromCurrentUser: false)
                                var meuser = userInfo[meindex]
                                var tauser = userInfo[taindex]
                                updateUser(user: meuser, message: msg)
                                updateUser(user: tauser, message: msg)
                                text = ""
                            }
                        }
```

relative function:

```
func judgemessage(message: Message) -> Bool{
        if ((message.FromUser == userInfo[meindex] || message.FromUser == userInfo[taindex])
            && (message.ToUser == userInfo[meindex] || message.ToUser == userInfo[taindex])) {
            if message.FromUser == userInfo[meindex] {
                message.isFromCurrentUser = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    
    func updateUser(user: User, message: Message) {
        user.chatContent.append(message)
        try? context.save()
    }
```

When I send, PreView crashed.
Chatgpt said that's because @Query is Read-Only, but didn't give suitable answer.
In fact, I can update when I use `onDisApper` but I want to update view in real time.

I run my app in simulator.And my app crash immediately.
Here is the thread:

```
Thread 1: "Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'FromUser' between objects in different contexts (source = <NSManagedObject: 0x6000021eed50> (entity: Message; id: 0x60000021e740 <x-coredata:///Message/tFA365848-2B47-4837-9232-4383D5835ACD6>; data: {\n    FromUser = nil;\n    ToUser = nil;\n    createdAt = \"2023-12-11 15:57:01 +0000\";\n    id = \"C94667F5-7BCB-4CE7-A402-1E24C1A46C7E\";\n    isFromCurrentUser = nil;\n    text = \"\\U4f60\\U597d\";\n}) , destination = <NSManagedObject: 0x6000021a7c00> (entity: User; id: 0x83ed50a83d12f62c <x-coredata://4D5F0C6F-92DC-4365-BA17-CF79DA19D9D5/User/p1>; data: {\n    Friend =     (\n        \"0x83ed50a83d06f62c <x-coredata://4D5F0C6F-92DC-4365-BA17-CF79DA19D9D5/User/p4>\"\n    );\n    UserName = \"\\U5b9d\\U8d1d\";\n    age = 20;\n    birthday = \"2003-09-29\";\n    chatContent =     (\n    );\n    id = \"FC77E985-1A6F-4DA0-A745-C8B0BB811294\";\n    imageFileName = \"FD8C475E-2A9B-49BF-BDA8-2D8DCFFD0374.png\";\n    inOthersPushMe = 0;\n    inPushToOthers = 0;\n    new = 1;\n    password = 88888888;\n    sex = "
```

Here is report:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'FromUser' between objects in different contexts (source = <NSManagedObject: 0x6000021eed50> (entity: Message; id: 0x60000021e740 <x-coredata:///Message/tFA365848-2B47-4837-9232-4383D5835ACD6>; data: {
    FromUser = nil;
    ToUser = nil;
    createdAt = "2023-12-11 15:57:01 +0000";
    id = "C94667F5-7BCB-4CE7-A402-1E24C1A46C7E";
    isFromCurrentUser = nil;
    text = "\U4f60\U597d";
}) , destination = <NSManagedObject: 0x6000021a7c00> (entity: User; id: 0x83ed50a83d12f62c <x-coredata://4D5F0C6F-92DC-4365-BA17-CF79DA19D9D5/User/p1>; data: {
    Friend =     (
        "0x83ed50a83d06f62c <x-coredata://4D5F0C6F-92DC-4365-BA17-CF79DA19D9D5/User/p4>"
    );
    UserName = "\U5b9d\U8d1d";
    age = 20;
    birthday = "2003-09-29";
    chatContent =     (
    );
    id = "FC77E985-1A6F-4DA0-A745-C8B0BB811294";
    imageFileName = "FD8C475E-2A9B-49BF-BDA8-2D8DCFFD0374.png";
    inOthersPushMe = 0;
    inPushToOthers = 0;
    new = 1;
    password = 88888888;
    sex = 1;
    "sign_hobbies" = "{length = 28, bytes = 0x5b22e5ad a6e4b9a0 222c22e7 9da1e8a7 ... e99885e8 afbb225d }";
    "sign_major" = "\U8ba1\U7b97\U673a\U79d1\U5b66\U4e0e\U6280\U672f";
    "sign_major_pre" = "{length = 61, bytes = 0x5b22e4ba a4e9809a e4bfa1e6 81afe5b7 ... e8bf90e8 be93225d }";
    "sign_mbti" = ENTP;
    "sign_others" = "{length = 2, bytes = 0x5b5d}";
    single = 1;
    stuId = 1;
    stuName = zzh;
}))'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80049928d __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff800063894 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreData                            0x00007ff806c593c3 _PFManagedObject_coerceValueForKeyWithDescription + 2086
    3   CoreData                            0x00007ff806c60e0b _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 177
    4   SwiftData                           0x00007ff8495afad9 $s9SwiftData015_DefaultBackingB0C15setRelationship5value3key13managedObjectyypSg_SSSo09NSManagedJ0CtFZ + 297
    5   SwiftData                           0x00007ff8495ae74d $s9SwiftData015_DefaultBackingB0C8setValue3key13managedObject03newF0ySS_So09NSManagedI0CypSgtFZ + 653
    6   SwiftData                           0x00007ff8495b2213 $s9SwiftData015_DefaultBackingB0C8setValue6forKey2toys0H4PathCyxqd__G_qd__tAA15PersistentModelRd__lF + 131
    7   SwiftData                           0x00007ff8495b5760 $s9SwiftData015_DefaultBackingB0CyxGAA0dB0A2aEP8setValue6forKey2toys0H4PathCy5ModelQzqd__G_qd__tAA010PersistentK0Rd__lFTW + 16
    8   Together With You                   0x000000010852bf3c $s17Together_With_You7MessageC8FromUserAA0F0Cvi + 140
    9   Together With You                   0x000000010852d0a5 $s17Together_With_You7MessageC2id4text9createdAt8FromUser02ToJ002isi7CurrentJ0AC10Foundation4UUIDV_SSAJ4DateVAA0J0CAPSbtcfc + 725
    10  Together With You                   0x000000010852cdc0 $s17Together_With_You7MessageC2id4text9createdAt8FromUser02ToJ002isi7CurrentJ0AC10Foundation4UUIDV_SSAJ4DateVAA0J0CAPSbtcfC + 112
    11  Together With You                   0x0000000108461588 $s17Together_With_You8ChatViewV4bodyQrvg7SwiftUI0E0PAEE7toolbar7contentQrqd__yXE_tAE14ToolbarContentRd__lFQOyAgEE29navigationBarTitleDisplayModeyQrAE010NavigationN4ItemV0opQ0OFQOyAgEE0mN16BackBut  12  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84ad919e8 block_destroy_helper + 68931
    13  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a450166 objectdestroyTm + 10997
    14  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a4553e6 objectdestroy.56Tm + 330
    15  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a45353f objectdestroyTm + 24270
    16  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a4534a7 objectdestroyTm + 24118
    17  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84aa4d8f8 objectdestroy.29Tm + 82651
    18  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84aa4cec8 objectdestroy.29Tm + 80043
    19  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84aa4c9b7 objectdestroy.29Tm + 78746
    20  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a60b51c get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzRld__C11Observation10ObservableRd__r__lAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA30_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierVyqd__SgGGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AjA0cK0HPyHCHCTm + 17800
    21  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a60b530 get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzRld__C11Observation10ObservableRd__r__lAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA30_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierVyqd__SgGGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AjA0cK0HPyHCHCTm + 17820
    22  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a60b51c get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzRld__C11Observation10ObservableRd__r__lAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA30_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierVyqd__SgGGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AjA0cK0HPyHCHCTm + 17800
    23  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84ad7f98c get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzlAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA30_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierVyAA11FocusEffectVGGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AiA0cI0HPyHCHCTm + 39392
    24  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84ad8003b get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzlAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA30_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierVyAA11FocusEffectVGGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AiA0cI0HPyHCHCTm + 41103
    25  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84af2f10a block_destroy_helper.21 + 3638
    26  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84acd7754 get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzlAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA12_FrameLayoutVGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AfA0C8ModifierHPyHCHCTm + 190757
    27  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84acd59e4 get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzlAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA12_FrameLayoutVGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AfA0C8ModifierHPyHCHCTm + 183221
    28  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84acd5b3f get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzlAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA12_FrameLayoutVGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AfA0C8ModifierHPyHCHCTm + 183568
    29  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84acd519f get_witness_table 7SwiftUI4ViewRzlAA15ModifiedContentVyxAA12_FrameLayoutVGAaBHPxAaBHD1__AfA0C8ModifierHPyHCHCTm + 181104
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8054f5daa -[UIGestureRecognizer _componentsEnded:withEvent:] + 142
    31  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805c1e113 -[UITouchesEvent _sendEventToGestureRecognizer:] + 662
    32  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff8054e4c84 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 483
    33  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805bbbc3e -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 5262
    34  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805b90e6c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 772
    35  UIKit                               0x00007ff8450e1fdf -[UIApplicationAccessibility sendEvent:] + 85
    36  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805c3db99 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 8406
    37  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805c40455 __processEventQueue + 8414
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805c368d6 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 163
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f5d0f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f5c51 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003f544e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 215
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003efb83 __CFRunLoopRun + 919
    43  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff8003ef409 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 557
    44  GraphicsServices                    0x00007ff80fcdd187 GSEventRunModal + 137
    45  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805b703a2 -[UIApplication _run] + 972
    46  UIKitCore                           0x00007ff805b74e10 UIApplicationMain + 123
    47  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a61077e __swift_memcpy18_8 + 2510
    48  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a610637 __swift_memcpy18_8 + 2183
    49  SwiftUI                             0x00007ff84a2bcaa5 objectdestroy.8Tm + 8912
    50  Together With You                   0x000000010854ddee $s17Together_With_You0a1_b1_C3AppV5$mainyyFZ + 30
    51  Together With You                   0x000000010854de89 main + 9
    52  dyld                                0x00000001088123ee start_sim + 10
    53  ???                 
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any help or advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried running it on a simulator to see what's causing the crash?

Comment: I agree, first we need to know if this is a preview issue only or not then we need to see the error message from the crash and what is User?

Comment: I am sorry for lack of information, I tried to run with simulator just now, and add information in my question. Sorry again for my nigligence.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, you are using different ModelContext objects  when creating objects and then it crashes when you try to create relationships between them.

Comment: That's true.But in fact I am a new developer, so I don't know how to modify it. And I can't search for relative answer to this question in Swift.